# SSL problems with WordPress

Tags: ssl

I want to use SSL with my WordPress installation but only on the admin interface (because it is self signed). Now my problem is that when I go to the main site I become redirected to the https version. How can I prevent this behavior so that **only** the admin interface is using ssl?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial to setup [Administration Over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) at the WordPress codex. It explains how to setup your configuration to use SSL on the Admin area.

Comment: Well I've tried this before but the problem is that if I activate SSL the whole site is using ssl not only the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force SSL and HTTPS on your WordPress admin area or login pages, then you need to configure SSL in the wp-config.php file.

Simply add the following code above the “That’s all, stop editing!” line in your wp-config.php file:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

This line allows WordPress to force SSL / HTTPs in WordPress admin area.

In your wp-config.php file add the following code to disable ssl for main website:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL',  'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://example.com');
```